# Is there a prohibition to live in a Moshav?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Tehilim says that Dovid didn't sit in a moshav leitzim (implying that we shouldn't either).

Is living in another moshav prohibited as "Chatzi Shiur"?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: One might try to bring a proof from "ומושב בני ישראל אשר ישבו במצרים," but in reality one can't say that because אין למדין מן קודם מתן תורה.

Comment: What if someone is a Leitz?

Comment: And what about a Yishuv Leitzim or a Kibbutz Leitzim - or a Kfar Leitzim. How could David have been so ambiguous?

Comment: @SethJ's question was [then asked separately](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26540).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While one might assume as you have asked, only bending at the knees constitute a chatzi shiur of moshav leitzim (well that and doing crunches). While Chazal made a gezeirah around this issur (prohibition) it only extends around the perimeter of Moshav Leitzim. Some have the custom against sitting in other moshavim, but standing in other moshavim is certainly permitted (at least with respect to our topic).

Answer (score 1):

There is Machloket in the Talmud Shushani between Rav Shtutz and Rav Orangutina about that. Rav Shtutz says that חצי שיעור of Moshav Leitzim is the T'chum Shabbat of the Moshav Leitzim and Rav Orangutina Says that every Moshav is חצי שיעור and Rav Yayintov Ben Shneimahot explains that Rav Shtutz is talking about the Tchum of every Moshav and is therefore Machmir more than Rav Orangutina. Rabeinu Chananshecicahr explains that the Tchum Rav Orangutina talked about was 12 Mil whilst Rav Shtutz talked about 2000 ama and the halachah is like him as it says in the Shulchan Karuch.