# Why did David only seem to prohibit a Moshav Leitzim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26524/) mentions the prohibition against living in a Moshav Leitzim.

My question is, what about a Yishuv Leitzim or a Kibbutz Leitzim or a Kfar Leitzim? How could David have been so ambiguous?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

He used the term מושב in particular because the numerical value of מושב לצים is 518 which is equivalent to "es hashem elokecha" (trust me, I am just not spelling out the shemos), meaning with God. He was hinting that if God is present also then it is permitted.

We know form Rabbeinu Moishy that "Hashem is here, and there, and everywhere!" as such in reality there is no prohibition ever of Moshav Letzim!

Answer (score 2):

King David specifically did not prohibit Kibbutz Leitzim and Asar Leitzim. He did not want to discourage people from visiting the PTIJ pages on Mi Yodeya. Since many people access Mi Yodeya from their mobile devices (while standing or traveling), it is not included in Moshav Leitzim.