# Where is a Leitz supposed to live?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If it's [prohibited to live among Leitzim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26540/), what is someone supposed to do if he *is* a [Leitz](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1325/leitz)? Just where exactly is he supposed to live?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: [Ir Leitzim, Israel](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1325/leitz)

Comment: בָּדָד יֵשֵׁב מִחוּץ לַמַּחֲנֶה מוֹשָׁבוֹ

Answer (score 6):

Per Divrei HaYomim1 16:32 a Leitz should live in the fields.

דברי הימים א: טז. לב.
ירעם הים ומלואו יע**לץ** השדה

Answer (score 2):

A leitz should live in a Moshav as it says in Tehillim Perek Aleph: "ובמושב ליצים לא ישב"' but you could interpert it two ways, or in a Moshav or a Moshav called Leitzim, so to be Yotzei Kol Safek you should live in the Moshav called Leitzim which can be found all over transjordan and beyond all the way to Iran.